# Overlay modal info for training/tutorial purposes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

On some sites I've seen a cool tutorial-type effect where they have almost a wizard-like pop up, describing how to use a website, it's controls, functions, etc. Perhaps an modal description pointing to a certain area, then you click on it and then the next area is highlighted and expounded upon, etc....

Question: Is there a jQuery, JS, CSS, bootstrap (or other) type solution that is easy to implement out there? Or is this something that I'll have to create myself?

Based on my research thus far, so far this is what I've been able to accomplish:

Using easyWizard plugin along with bootstrap I've been able to create a modal wizard. The problem is the position is static and the entire background is disabled/dimmed (due to the modal effect).

What I would like is for each "step" to show up near the control(s) it's describing and for the user to be able to see the actual control(s) being highlighted/described. An added plus would be the ability to dim the whole page with the exception of the control(s). Alternatively a red box around the control(s) being discussed or similar implementation.

Any implementation thoughts or suggestions on this would be appreciated.